# Нажатие по вложенному элементу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть изображение над которым применяется событие клика, после чего изображение исчезает и появляются 4 блока. Как сделать, чтобы при повторном клике взаимодействие шло с появившимися блоками, а не с родителем?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').on('click', function() {
    a = '.' + $(this).attr("class");
    console.log(a);
    $(this).empty();
    $(toper()).appendTo(this);
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
})

function toper() {
  b = a.slice(1);
  for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    var c = '<div class="' + b + i + '">' +  i + '</div > ';
    $(c).appendTo(a).addClass('size');
}}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.content,
.contentt {
  width: 624px;
  height: 624px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 12px auto 0 auto;
}
.content1,
.content2,
.content3,
.content4 {
  background: #789;
}
.size {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <img src="http://www.artscroll.ru/Images/2008/a/Alexander%20Jansson/000017.jpg" alt="Изображение не загрузилось :-(">
</div>
```

Comment: а что должно быть при повторном клике

Comment: @L.Vadim при повторном клике в моей программе кликало по классу content, а не по созданным новым дивам из функции toper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выключите событие `Click`:

```
$(this).off('click')
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').on('click', function() {
    a = '.' + $(this).attr("class");
    console.log(a);
    $(this).empty();
    $(toper()).appendTo(this);
    $(this).off('click') //отключаем обработчик клика
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
})

function toper() {
  b = a.slice(1);
  for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    var c = '<div class="' + b + i + '">' +  i + '</div > ';
    $(c).appendTo(a).addClass('size').on('click', function() {
          console.log('нажат внутренний див', $(this).text());
    })
}}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.content,
.contentt {
  width: 624px;
  height: 624px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 12px auto 0 auto;
}
.content1,
.content2,
.content3,
.content4 {
  background: #789;
}
.size {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <img src="http://www.artscroll.ru/Images/2008/a/Alexander%20Jansson/000017.jpg" alt="Изображение не загрузилось :-(">
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, как раз то, что нужно